# Input resource must be set issue in FlatfileitemReader with multiresourceitemreader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

i have configured spring batch with multiresourceitemreader which delegated to flatfileitemreader.Even then the flatfileitemreader is explitly insisting to set resource. what would be the solution?

For reading multiple files from a directory we need to MultiResouceItemReader where we specify the directory resource location and then set the delegation to FlatFileItemReader to actually read the file.so there is no need to set a resource as we set when we just used FlatFileItemReader to read a single file.
but when i am not setting the resouce(not specifying any file location) , while running it is giving error as : input resource must be set? I explored and many sites are not setting up the resource in FlatFileItemReader when reading multiple files.

for reference :

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-multiresourceitemreader-example/
Please see the configuration for flatfileitemreader in "resources/spring/batch/jobs/job-read-files.xml" file.

Comment: Please rewrite or add more info or I think this question will be closed shortly...

Comment: at least add the used spring xml/javaconfig

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use multiResourceReader in place of flatFileItemReader while defining **batch:chunk** tag.

For example:

```
<batch:chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="oracleItemWriter" processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="1000">
```

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Pratik